# Bootstrap Nav-List alignment / browser compatibility

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the below to create a nav-list in my bootstrap based Rails app:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
  <li class="nav-header">Going out</li>
    <% @event_types.each do |et| %>
      <li>
       <a href="/events?event_type=<%= et.id %>">
       <div class="span2"><%= et.event_type %></div>
       <div><span class="badge badge-success"><%= et.events.future_events_count %></span></div></a>
      </li>
   <% end %>
</ul>
```

I thought this was looking ok until it was pointed out that it's misaligned in Internet Explorer!!

My site is here: [www.wozzoncornwall.co.uk](http://www.wozzoncornwall.co.uk) , if you view in Chrome for example it looks fine. View in IE and you'll see what I mean. Does anyone know how to modify this to maintain event types on the left and event counts on the right so it's cross browser compatible?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks the same for me in IE9 and chrome!! Is this a low version IE problem?

Comment: Are the event types and counts horizontally aligned? I've only tried it in an emulator (http://netrenderer.com/) and it looks terrible on all IE versions. My partner us using IE9 on his PC and it's misaligned for him!?! Think I should recode this though, at least until I can get it to render as expected in the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured this our myself. Here's how for anyone else having the same issue.

Basically, I dropped the two divs inside the li tag and then used bootstraps pull-right helper class:

```
<% @event_types.each do |et| %>
    <li>
      <a href="/events?event_type=<%= et.id %>">
        <%= et.event_type %>
            <span class="badge badge-success pull-right"><%= et.events.future_events_count %></span>
        </a>
    </li>
<% end %>
```